# Как вычислить сумму с произведением по формуле

Tags: c++, массивы, математика, циклы, ряды

нужна помощь, вообще не пойму как решить данную задачу..
Дан массив x из 55 чисел. Вычислить

```
x0*(x1+x2) * (x3+x4+x5) *... *(x45+x46++...+x54)
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Как подставить числа в формулу?

Comment: У Вас, начиная с третьего числа и до 55 числа повторяется одна и та же последовательность действий; умножить то, что получилось на предыдущем шаге на сумму из трех последовательных чисел. Распишите эти действия, засуньте их в цикл, определите стартовые условия для цикла и границы цикл. Делов на 5 минут. Приступайте. Будут конкретные вопросы ответим.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Не, не трёх... там походу в каждой следующей скобке на 1 слагаемое больше...

Comment: @Akina, да не заметил, но это не сильно усложняет дело. Особенно если человек знает, как считать сумму арифметической прогрессии.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов *Особенно если человек знает, как считать сумму арифметической прогрессии.* Да нету там прогрессии. Есть "треугольные числа".

Comment: @Akina, да Вы правы, я сегодня невнимателен, но это не усложняет задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вложенный цикл с изменяющейся границей цикла и общим счетчиком. Примерно так:

```
double x[55];

double prod = 1;
for(int count = 1, m = 0; m < 55 ;++count)
{
    double term = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        term += x[m++];
    }
    prod *= term;
}

cout << prod << endl;
```